# How to adapt Bosch Sensor API's to use with STM32?

Tags: c++, c, stm32, sensors

I have two Bosch sensors model BMI160 and BMP388. I am trying to use these sensors with my STM32 based NUCLEO board. I am using CubeIDE and C to code STM32.

Bosch has APIs for its sensors and they are pretty detailed. However, as far as I understand, a wrapper needs to be written in order to provide I2C or SPI connection.

https://github.com/BoschSensortec/BMP3-Sensor-API

Let me give an example from BMP388. Besides the main .c and .h files of the API, there are common.c and common.h files. As far as I understand interface communication happens via these files. In the standard version, "coines" protocol is used, but I need to convert it to STM32 HAL I2C communication for both sensors.

For the BMP388 I created something like this:

```
BMP3_INTF_RET_TYPE bmp3_i2c_read(uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t * reg_data, uint32_t len, void * intf_ptr);
BMP3_INTF_RET_TYPE bmp3_i2c_write(uint8_t reg_addr,
  const uint8_t * reg_data, uint32_t len, void * intf_ptr);

uint8_t GTXBuffer[512], GRXBuffer[2048];
int8_t SensorAPI_I2Cx_Read(uint8_t subaddress, uint8_t * pBuffer, uint32_t ReadNumbr, void * intf_ptr) {
  uint8_t dev_addr = * (uint8_t * ) intf_ptr;
  uint16_t DevAddress = dev_addr << 1;

  // send register address
  HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit( & I2C_HANDLE, DevAddress, & subaddress, 1, BUS_TIMEOUT);
  HAL_I2C_Master_Receive( & I2C_HANDLE, DevAddress, pBuffer, ReadNumbr, BUS_TIMEOUT);
  return 0;
}

int8_t SensorAPI_I2Cx_Write(uint8_t subaddress, uint8_t * pBuffer, uint32_t WriteNumbr, void * intf_ptr) {
  uint8_t dev_addr = * (uint8_t * ) intf_ptr;
  uint16_t DevAddress = dev_addr << 1;

  GTXBuffer[0] = subaddress;
  memcpy( & GTXBuffer[1], pBuffer, WriteNumbr);

  // send register address
  HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit( & I2C_HANDLE, DevAddress, GTXBuffer, WriteNumbr + 1, BUS_TIMEOUT);
  return 0;
}
```

But I have no idea how to edit common.c and common.h to be able to run this function.

Standart common.c file for BMP388, which uses COINES.

```
/**\
 * Copyright (c) 2021 Bosch Sensortec GmbH. All rights reserved.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
 **/

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "bmp3.h"
#include "coines.h"
#include "common.h"

/*! BMP3 shuttle board ID */
#define BMP3_SHUTTLE_ID  0xD3

/* Variable to store the device address */
static uint8_t dev_addr;

/*!
 * I2C read function map to COINES platform
 */
BMP3_INTF_RET_TYPE bmp3_i2c_read(uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *reg_data, uint32_t len, void *intf_ptr)
{
    uint8_t dev_addr = *(uint8_t*)intf_ptr;

    return coines_read_i2c(dev_addr, reg_addr, reg_data, (uint16_t)len);
}

/*!
 * I2C write function map to COINES platform
 */
BMP3_INTF_RET_TYPE bmp3_i2c_write(uint8_t reg_addr, const uint8_t *reg_data, uint32_t len, void *intf_ptr)
{
    uint8_t dev_addr = *(uint8_t*)intf_ptr;

    return coines_write_i2c(dev_addr, reg_addr, (uint8_t *)reg_data, (uint16_t)len);
}

/*!
 * SPI read function map to COINES platform
 */
BMP3_INTF_RET_TYPE bmp3_spi_read(uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *reg_data, uint32_t len, void *intf_ptr)
{
    uint8_t dev_addr = *(uint8_t*)intf_ptr;

    return coines_read_spi(dev_addr, reg_addr, reg_data, (uint16_t)len);
}

/*!
 * SPI write function map to COINES platform
 */
BMP3_INTF_RET_TYPE bmp3_spi_write(uint8_t reg_addr, const uint8_t *reg_data, uint32_t len, void *intf_ptr)
{
    uint8_t dev_addr = *(uint8_t*)intf_ptr;

    return coines_write_spi(dev_addr, reg_addr, (uint8_t *)reg_data, (uint16_t)len);
}

/*!
 * Delay function map to COINES platform
 */
void bmp3_delay_us(uint32_t period, void *intf_ptr)
{
    coines_delay_usec(period);
}

void bmp3_check_rslt(const char api_name[], int8_t rslt)
{
    switch (rslt)
    {
        case BMP3_OK:

            /* Do nothing */
            break;
        case BMP3_E_NULL_PTR:
            printf("API [%s] Error [%d] : Null pointer\r\n", api_name, rslt);
            break;
        case BMP3_E_COMM_FAIL:
            printf("API [%s] Error [%d] : Communication failure\r\n", api_name, rslt);
            break;
        case BMP3_E_INVALID_LEN:
            printf("API [%s] Error [%d] : Incorrect length parameter\r\n", api_name, rslt);
            break;
        case BMP3_E_DEV_NOT_FOUND:
            printf("API [%s] Error [%d] : Device not found\r\n", api_name, rslt);
            break;
        case BMP3_E_CONFIGURATION_ERR:
            printf("API [%s] Error [%d] : Configuration Error\r\n", api_name, rslt);
            break;
        case BMP3_W_SENSOR_NOT_ENABLED:
            printf("API [%s] Error [%d] : Warning when Sensor not enabled\r\n", api_name, rslt);
            break;
        case BMP3_W_INVALID_FIFO_REQ_FRAME_CNT:
            printf("API [%s] Error [%d] : Warning when Fifo watermark level is not in limit\r\n", api_name, rslt);
            break;
        default:
            printf("API [%s] Error [%d] : Unknown error code\r\n", api_name, rslt);
            break;
    }
}

BMP3_INTF_RET_TYPE bmp3_interface_init(struct bmp3_dev *bmp3, uint8_t intf)
{
    int8_t rslt = BMP3_OK;
    struct coines_board_info board_info;

    if (bmp3 != NULL)
    {
        int16_t result = coines_open_comm_intf(COINES_COMM_INTF_USB);
        if (result < COINES_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf(
                "\n Unable to connect with Application Board ! \n" " 1. Check if the board is connected and powered on. \n" " 2. Check if Application Board USB driver is installed. \n"
                " 3. Check if board is in use by another application. (Insufficient permissions to access USB) \n");
            exit(result);
        }

        result = coines_get_board_info(&board_info);

#if defined(PC)
        setbuf(stdout, NULL);
#endif

        if (result == COINES_SUCCESS)
        {
            if ((board_info.shuttle_id != BMP3_SHUTTLE_ID))
            {
                printf("! Warning invalid sensor shuttle \n ," "This application will not support this sensor \n");
                exit(COINES_E_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        coines_set_shuttleboard_vdd_vddio_config(0, 0);
        coines_delay_msec(1000);

        /* Bus configuration : I2C */
        if (intf == BMP3_I2C_INTF)
        {
            printf("I2C Interface\n");
            dev_addr = BMP3_ADDR_I2C_PRIM;
            bmp3->read = bmp3_i2c_read;
            bmp3->write = bmp3_i2c_write;
            bmp3->intf = BMP3_I2C_INTF;
            coines_config_i2c_bus(COINES_I2C_BUS_0, COINES_I2C_STANDARD_MODE);
        }
        /* Bus configuration : SPI */
        else if (intf == BMP3_SPI_INTF)
        {
            printf("SPI Interface\n");
            dev_addr = COINES_SHUTTLE_PIN_7;
            bmp3->read = bmp3_spi_read;
            bmp3->write = bmp3_spi_write;
            bmp3->intf = BMP3_SPI_INTF;
            coines_config_spi_bus(COINES_SPI_BUS_0, COINES_SPI_SPEED_7_5_MHZ, COINES_SPI_MODE0);
        }

        coines_delay_msec(1000);

        coines_set_shuttleboard_vdd_vddio_config(3300, 3300);

        coines_delay_msec(1000);

        bmp3->delay_us = bmp3_delay_us;
        bmp3->intf_ptr = &dev_addr;
    }
    else
    {
        rslt = BMP3_E_NULL_PTR;
    }

    return rslt;
}

void bmp3_coines_deinit(void)
{
    fflush(stdout);

    coines_set_shuttleboard_vdd_vddio_config(0, 0);
    coines_delay_msec(1000);

    /* Coines interface reset */
    coines_soft_reset();
    coines_delay_msec(1000);
    coines_close_comm_intf(COINES_COMM_INTF_USB);
}
```

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://community.bosch-sensortec.com/t5/MEMS-sensors-forum/Implementation-of-BMI160-Driver/td-p/10394

Comment: Thanks @jspcal this will be very useful for me.

Comment: Where is C++ code here? Why do you use both tags? It is basically spam to drive more attention

Answer (score 0):

it should be sufficient to substitute the coin functions with the ones you wrote.

For instance:

Substitute:

```
return coines_read_i2c(dev_addr, reg_addr, reg_data, (uint16_t)len);
```

with:

```
SensorAPI_I2Cx_Read(dev_addr, reg_addr, reg_data, (uint16_t)len)
```

you then just need to check that the calls are compatible types